# How to run unit tests in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am having a difficult time understanding how to use assertions in unit tests in Python.

Original code:

```
class A:
   def method(file):
       if file:
          <do something>
       else:
          raise Exception("file not found")
```

Now to create its test. Let's say I don't want to pass a file and test it.

```
t1 = A()
class Test(TestCase):
    def test_method_no_path(self):
         t1.method(' ') #passed no file
         <Now do what> ?? 
         self.assert ??
```

Comment: You need to assert that something happens in your `<do something>` section.

Comment: btw, there are lots of things wrong here. Your title asks how to *run* unittests, but the body of your question is about *using* assertions. Your `class A` has a method with no `self` parameter. Your test instantiates `t1` outside the test class and the `test_method_no_path` seems to be passing in a `file` which will pass the `if file:` test.

Comment: Well, what do you *want* to test here? What behaviour do you want to test happening or not happening?

Comment: What exactly you would assert on depends on what `<do something>` actually does, as you passed a truth-y argument. You test what the method does, and we can't tell much about what that is from `method`.

Comment: So I need to revise the source code first ? I have never written tests before and it's been a day I am trying.

Comment: We can't tell you that, we don't know: what the source is; what it's _supposed_ to do; how you've tried to test it; what the problem with that was. Give a [mre].

Comment: If you are having this much trouble, I suggest starting with something much more simple. Plus you need to be aware of how to write classes and methods.

Comment: Maybe start with a tutorial, something like https://realpython.com/python-testing/

Comment: @titan575 thank you. a little reputation as a gift from me. good luck ;)

Comment: @DanilaGanchar no thanks to you! I just needed a kickstart. Now I am able to write unit tests.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
# tests/test_ex.py    
from os import path
from unittest import TestCase


class Error(Exception):
    pass


class FileChecker:
    def process_file(self, f_path: str):
        if path.exists(f_path) and path.isfile(f_path):
            # just an example
            return 'result'
        raise Error(f_path)


class TestFileChecker(TestCase):
    _CHECKER = FileChecker()

    def test_done(self):
        # check method result
        self.assertTrue(self._CHECKER.process_file('/tmp/1.txt') == 'result')

    def test_error(self):
        # check method exception
        with self.assertRaises(Error):
            self._CHECKER.process_file('/tmp/1.txt')
```

Run our test(`nosetests tests/test_ex.py`). `test_done` failed because `/tmp/1.txt` file does not exist:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_done (tests.test_ex.TestFileChecker)
```

Let's create a file(`echo 'test' >> /tmp/1.txt`) and run test one more time:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_error (tests.test_ex.TestFileChecker)
```

As you can see `test_done` works fine, because we got expected result, but now we have problems with `test_error`(because `Error` wasn't raised).